# Need to access a piece of state inside of action creator

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to access a piece of state from a different reducer in my action creator.  I know there's a ton of questions out there like this already, but so far, I'm still hung up on why this isn't working even after reading them.  My action creator takes a JSON from Firebase and filters it according to another piece of state called 'search' from the searching reducer.  Here's that code:

Action Creator:

```
 export const searchResult = () => {
   const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
      firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/entries`)
         .orderByChild('uid')
            .on('value', snapshot => {
                const myObj = snapshot.val();
                const { search } = getState().searching;
                const list = _.pickBy(myObj, (((value) => 
                      value.make.indexOf(search) !== -1 || 
                      value.model.indexOf(search) !== -1));

    dispatch({ type: SEARCH_RESULT_SUCCESS, payload: list });
    });
   };
  };
```

And here's the Action Creator for the text input of the search filter:

```
 export const searchChanged = (text) => {
   return {
      type: SEARCH_CHANGED,
      payload: text
  };
 };
```

And here's the reducer for searchResult called entryReducer:

```
import {
   SEARCH_RESULT_SUCCESS,
   ENTRY_FETCH_SUCCESS,
   SOLD_RESULT_SUCCESS
 } from '../actions/types';

 const INITIAL_STATE = [];

 export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
       case ENTRY_FETCH_SUCCESS:
          return action.payload;
       case SEARCH_RESULT_SUCCESS:
          return action.payload;
       case SOLD_RESULT_SUCCESS:
          return action.payload;
       default:
          return state;
    }
  };
```

And here's the searchReducer:

```
 import {
    SEARCH_CHANGED,
 } from '../actions/types';

 const INITIAL_STATE = {
     search: '',
 };

 export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
         case SEARCH_CHANGED:
             return { ...state, search: action.payload };
         default:
             return state;
     }
    };
```

And here's the combineReducers function:

```
 import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
 import AuthReducer from './AuthReducer';
 import EntryFormReducer from './EntryFormReducer';
 import EntryReducer from './EntryReducer';
 import SearchReducer from './SearchReducer';
 import PasswordReducer from './PasswordReducer';

 export default combineReducers({
   auth: AuthReducer,
   entryForm: EntryFormReducer,
   employees: EntryReducer,
   searching: SearchReducer,
   pw: PasswordReducer

 });
```

Here's where I call searchResult():

```
class EmployeeList extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
     this.props.searchResult();
```

And my mapStateToProps():

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const employees = _.map(state.employees, (val, uid) => {
       return { ...val, uid };
  });

   return { employees };
 };

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { searchResult, entryClear, 
   logoutUser })(EmployeeList);
```

And here's where searchChanged() is called inside the component Search:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { View } from 'react-native';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 import { Icon } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
 import { searchChanged, searchResult } from '../actions';
 import Card from './common/Card';
 import CardSection from './common/CardSection';
 import Input from './common/Input';


 class Search extends Component {

  onSearchChange(text) {
    this.props.searchChanged(text);
        searchResult();
 }
```

The code runs just fine, but nothing changes when I type into the search filter text input.  I can see that my piece of state called 'search' from the 'searching' reducer gets updated.  But my action creator 'searchResult' isn't accessing it to filter by it.  Any help would be appreciated...I'm new to redux.

Comment: Can we see how you call `searchResult`

Comment: A problem is in your action creator. Looks like you are missing a `)` at the end of the `_.pickBy` call. I didn't create an answer though as I'm not certain that is the only issue.

Comment: @TravisWhite Yeah, I erased some restrictions on the pickBy() just to make it less convoluted, but that's not the problem cuz the original code has the parenthesis.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Li357 I edited the answer so you can see searchResult().  Let me know if you need anything else.  Thanks so much for taking the time to look through my code.

Comment: @JaredNelson If you're trying to search every time the user inputs, you should call the function when the input value is changed, not on component mount

Comment: @Li357 That makes sense, I added the code where searchResult() and searchChanged() are called.  I think this is what you were after in the first place.  Wouldn't this fulfill the requirement that it be called every time the user input value is changed?